# La primera imagen de mi slider se visualiza bien en HTML, pero no en PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

Estoy realizando un shortcode de un slider que muestre mis featured posts de WP y que tenga la posibilidad de abrir los detalles de cada post mediante un div oculto.
El slider está basado en este de w3schools (del que se puede ver el código y testear online desde esta dirección: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

El problema es que el slider tan sólo es visible en php una vez hago clic en la flecha de siguiente y a partir de ahí funciona correctamente. No sé el motivo, puesto que en HTML funciona correctamente.

**Mi CSS:**

```
    #slider {
        width: 70%;
        
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .slide {display: none;}
```

**Mi PHP:**

```
     <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ob_start();?>

   <div id="slider" class="slider">
   <div class="arrows">
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a></div>

 <?php
 while( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post(); 
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post- 
        >ID), '');
        $featuredID = get_post_thumbnail_id();?>

        <div class="slide fade" id="slide">
        <h2 class="zz-sc-jscss"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        By <?php the_author(); ?> on <?php echo get_the_date( 'l, F d, Y' ); 
       ?>
      <?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>
   <?php 
   echo "<div"; echo ' class="n"'; echo "id=".$featuredID.">";
   $info = $featuredID;echo "</div>";
     
    ?> <div class="open">
<?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID);?>
<span class="cerrar">X</span></div></div>
   
   
<?php endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
  }
```

**Mi JS:**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: ¿En qué parte del DOM estás cargando el código Javascript? ¿Ese es todo tu código JS? Convendría ponerlo dentro de un [listener de `DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero eso no explicaría que se vea bien en HTML. Lo pruebo igualmente. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La sugerencia de la respuesta anterior ha solucionado el problema. Gracias mil A. Ceano.
Convenía ponerlo dentro de un listener de DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Hola, por favor no utilices el area de respuestas para agregar comentarios